# Colocar tiempo dentro de divs (Contador)

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo este contador que encontré en un sitio y funciona bien, pero no logro meter cada variable en una etiqueta.

también cree varios divs y con diferentes id, pero se duplica a medida que va pasando los segundos, y pues se hace una lista hacia abajo.

```
if ($("body").hasClass("home")) {
                var end = new Date('11/22/2019 4:00 PM');

                var _second = 1000;
                var _minute = _second * 60;
                var _hour = _minute * 60;
                var _day = _hour * 24;
                var timer;

                function showRemaining() {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var distance = end - now;
                    if (distance < 0) {

                        clearInterval(timer);
                        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                        return;
                    }
                    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);


                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = + '<p>' + days + '</p>';
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<p>' + hours + '</p>';
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<p>' + minutes + '</p>';
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<p>' + seconds + '</p>';
                }

                timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
            }
```

lo intente tambien asi, pero el salen varios "p" y la idea es que se mantenga en una sola etiqueta, es decir sin duplicarse

```
$('#countdown').append('<p>' + seconds + '</p>');
```

aqui llega el tiempo regresivo

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En base a lo que entendí, debes tomar en cuenta que estás utilizando apunta al `body`, por lo cual debes apuntar al `div` que tu quieres, en este caso al `div` con un `id = "countdown"`, así `$("#countdown")`, te dejo el ejemplo:

```js
if ($("#countdown").hasClass("home")) {
                var end = new Date('11/22/2019 4:00 PM');
                var _second = 1000;
                var _minute = _second * 60;
                var _hour = _minute * 60;
                var _day = _hour * 24;
                var timer;

                function showRemaining() {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var distance = end - now;
                    if (distance < 0) {

                        clearInterval(timer);
                        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                        return;
                    }
                    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);


                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = + '<p>' + days + '</p>';
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<p class="mBlue">' + hours + '</p>';
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<p class="mYellow">' + minutes + '</p>';
                    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += '<p class="mGreen">' + seconds + '</p>';
                }

                timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
            }
```

```css
.mBlue{
  color: blue;
}
.mYellow{
  color: Yellow;
}
.mGreen{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="countdown" class="home"></div>
```

Si no responde tu pregunta se más específico en lo que solicitas, así podremos ir modificando la respuesta.

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: mmmm, el if es para que la funcion solo se ejecute en el home y no en alguna interna, es decir no tiene nada que ver

Comment: lo que quiero es meter a days hours etc, dentro de una etiqueta, ya que salen en el DOM  sin nada y asi no puedo meterle estilos

Comment: no me queda claro, los valores están dentro del div con un id="countdown", por qué no podrías agregar estilos a esa etiqueta?.... o lo que deseas es que a cada uno de los número tenga sus estilos?... quieres que cada uno esté en un div distinto?

Comment: que cada uno de los numeros tenga su div o etiqueta para darle estilos

Comment: ¿Y si agregas directamente un llamado a una clase de estilos desde el InnerHtml?... Esto es lo que quieres?... te dejo el ejemplo.

Comment: pero porque sera que los dias me sale en NaN? :(

Comment: Por lo que veo es por el la función Math.Floor, ya que la división entre "distance/ _day" da un valor cero y estás tratando con fechas, te anexo la ruta de la documentación https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/floor . Busca e imprime el resultado y poco a poco llega a tu conclusión de porqué sucede, en caso de que estés atorado te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta para resolver este tema.

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict"

$(document).ready(function(){
        var end = new Date('11/30/2019 4:00 PM');

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            $('#dias').html('<p>' + days + '</p>');
            $('#horas').html('<p>' + hours + '</p>');
            $('#minutos').html('<p>' + minutes + '</p>');
            $('#segundos').html('<p>' + seconds + '</p>');
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dias" ></div>
        <div id="horas" ></div>
        <div id="minutos" ></div>
        <div id="segundos"></div>      
    </body>
</html>
```